# Substr if preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I am doing a simple text based chatting game (PHP+Mysql). I would like to do some interest response/function when user key in some coding.

Example: I allowed user to search for help, they can simply type `#help#` in the chatbar and Enter, then will popup a help center to them. They also can chat in different chatroom, but when they type `#cAll# Hello every one` and Enter, All chatroom can see the `Hello every one`. But how do I only catch the `Hello every one` without the `#cAll#`?

My current coding as below:

```
$chatting = addslashes($_GET['chatting']);
preg_match("/(?<=#).*?(?=#)/", $chatting, $match);
if($match[0] == 'cAll'){
    $data['ctype'] = 1;//show to all chatroom
    $chatting = ???? //i would like catch the $chatting without #cAll#
}
if($match[0] == 'help'){
    //my popup help coding...
}
$chatting = iconv('UTF-8',$_G['chatset'],$chatting);
$data['areaid'] = $chatroomid;
$data['ctext'] = $chatting;
C::t('#'.$jn.'#'.$jn.'_chatting')->insert($data);//my template language to insert the data to database
```

Beside that, how to `response` only when the `#keyword#` is match in front of user sentence?

Example:

response only `#cAll# hello world` or `#cAll#hello world`

do not response `hello world #cAll#`

do not response `hello #cAll# world`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a pattern with 2 capturing groups where the `#` part starts at the beginning of the string to prevent it to come after the user sentence as in the examples.

In group 1 capture what is between 2 `#` and in group 2 capture what comes after it.

```
^#(\w+)#\h*(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `#(\w+)#` Match 1+ word chars between `#` in **group 1**
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitspace chars to not capture those
- `(.+)` Match 1+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLuQM5/1)

Then you can use the value of group 1 to check for `cAll` and use the value of group 2 for the chatting.

For example:

```
if (preg_match("/^#(\w+)#\h*(.+)/", $chatting, $match)) {
    if ($match[1] == 'cAll') {
        $data['ctype'] = 1;//show to all chatroom
        $chatting = $match[2];
    }
}
```

If the pattern could match more than word character between the `#` and the chatting should contain at least a single non whitespace char:

```
^#([^\r\n#]+)#\h*(\S.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LgvPRw/1)